# How to join only latest date values from another table and prevent duplication

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

I'm trying to lookup a unique value from table b and get it into table a.
Table b stores multiple values that are changing by date.
I would like to join but only getting the values with the latest date from table b.

## Table a

```
Unique ID 
1
2
```

## Table b

```
Date           Unique ID  Price
01/01/2019     1          100
01/02/2019     1          101
01/03/2019     1          102
01/01/2019     2          90
01/02/2019     2          91
01/03/2019     2          92
```

Expected result

```
Unique ID      Price      Date
1              102        01/03/2019
2              92         01/03/2019
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub-query that returns each UniqueID together with its max date. `IN` that result.

```
select * from tablename
where (UniqueID, date) in (select UniqueID, max(date)
                           from tablename
                           group by UniqueID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want *correlated* subquery :

```
select b.*
from tableb b
where b.date = (select max(b1.date) from tableb b1 where b1.UniqueID = b.UniqueID);
```

If you want to go with `JOIN` then you can do `JOIN` with subquery :

```
select a.UniqueID , b.Price, b.Date
from tablea a inner join
     tableb b
     on b.UniqueID = a.UniqueID 
where b.date = (select max(b1.date) from tableb b1 where b1.UniqueID = a.UniqueID);
```

Comment: thanks a lot Yogesh!I actually have more columns in table a (and I also running some aggregations on those columns) so I think I need a join.

Comment: thanks! However I am getting error #3782 "Improper Column Reference in the search condition of a Joined Table" - I am running the query on Teradata. When I removed other joins I had, it took A LOT of time to run the query which should return around 50 rows

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery?

```
select b.*
from b
where b.date = (select max(b2.date) from b b2 where b2.unique_id = b.unique_id);
```

Comment: thanks a lot Gordon! I actually have more columns in table a (and I also running some aggregations on those columns) so I think I need a join.

Comment: @OrTzidki . . . You can add the `JOIN` to this query.  It is not necessary for the question you actually asked.

Comment: I want my main table to be table 1 since most of the fields are there